# Setting header in Web.HttpClient to contain quotations

Tags: javascript, post, winjs

I'm trying to make a POST request using Web.HttpClient (JavaScript)

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(baseURL);
var hc = new Web.HttpClient();
var authHeader = "OAuth authSig=\"dsadsASD\", timestamp=\"123132\"";
var request = new Web.HttpRequestMessage(Web.HttpMethod.post, uri);

request.headers.insert("Authorization", authHeader);

hc.sendRequestAsync(request);
```

However this is setting the Authorization header to:

```
authSig=dsadsASD, timestamp=123132
```

instead of:

```
authSig="dsadsASD", timestamp="123132"
```

Any thoughts why? or how I can get around this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged as .NET/C#?

Comment: I'm using the JavaScript version of HttpClient not C#

Comment: What `Authorization` scheme are you using? The syntax you're using doesn't conform to the specification. (Further, and more interestingly, if I take your code and try it on Win 8.1 Update 1, it fails when trying to `insert` that string).

Comment: It failed because I hadn't included the OAuth prefix, should run now. But you can se it strips the double quote from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the authorization this way:

```
var WebHttp = Windows.Web.Http; // just to fit in StackOverflow :)
var authHdr = new WebHttp.Headers.HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("OAuth", 
                   authHeader);

request.headers.authorization = authHdr;
```

The quotes are not stripped from the value.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to take a look at the WebAuthenticationBroker [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122/view/SourceCode).

Comment: Sorted it out, probably should be using strongly typed headers anyway. thanks!